# Find text matching a RegExp near my cursor in Google Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a document that has text that I can match with [this](http://www.regexr.com/3ccvg) regular expression. I would like to find the text near the cursor in Google Docs that matches that regular expression and add a hyperlink to it.

The problem is that for whatever reason, the regular expression does not seem to be finding the text. As a result, I'm getting errors because (essentiality) it can't add a hyperlink to "null".

The Google Doc is [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1It7SZiDiiossxMkqiu5FUjMe4MItVfNHN3iU-ApNF1s) (some hyperlinks have been already added manually, I'm trying to automate it so it's simpler to add them).

This is the code I'm currently using:

```js
function Insert_Link() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var Title = doc.getName();
  var elements = doc.getCursor().getSurroundingText();
  var element = elements.findText(/\d(-|\d|:|;|,)+/);
  var startOffset = element.getStartOffset();
  var endOffset = element.getEndOffsetInclusive();
  var selection = element.asText();
  var selectedText = selection.getText();
  selectedText = selectedText.substring(startOffset, endOffset + 1).trim();
  var reference = Title.replace(/(\(.*\))/, "").replace(/^\d{1,2}/, "") + " " + selectedText;
  Ref2Link(reference, selection, startOffset, endOffset);
}
```

I'm sure I'm making some stupid mistake, but I can't tell what that is. If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please change '\' to double '\'.

I change your Doc's code too.

Please try it.

ref:Special Characters (JavaScript)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yfce773(v=vs.94).aspx

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for `findText()` says:

> A subset of the JavaScript regular expression features are not fully supported, such as capture groups and mode modifiers.

Further, `searchPattern` is supposed to be a String, not a RegExp. (Tricky!)

Your RegExp includes a capture group. This one will match the same groupings, without a capture group:

```
var element = elements.findText("\d[-\d:;,]+");
```

Comment: Interesting.  Unfortunately, when I make that change, I still get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot call method "getStartOffset" of null.`  I'm sure those changes were necessary, but it seems that there is also another change that needs to be made somewhere.